# Passing parameter to completeMethod of p:autoComplete

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm using the PrimeFaces `p:autoComplete` widget in a search form of my project. The user can choose how many and which form-elements (search parameters) he wants to include so I need to pass an ID to the `completeMethod` for each of them. I've tried adding `onfocus=".."` to pass the object to the bean but that only would be activated when the element first is loaded.

My question: How can I pass an attribute to the `completeMethod`?

XHTML of the element (simple):

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{filter.value}" label="dynamic search attribute"
                completeMethod="#{myBean.complete}" />
```

The bean (simple):

```
@Named("myBean")
public class MyController implements Serializable {

    public List<String> complete(String query) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        // ... code
        return results;
    }
}
```

In theory this would seem like the perfect solution:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{filter.value}" label="dynamic search attribute"
                completeMethod="#{myBean.complete(filter)}" />
```

And again the bean:

```
@Named("myBean")
public class MyController implements Serializable {

    public List<String> complete(String query, FilterObject o) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        // ... database query based on FilterObject o
        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can set it as an attribute:

```xml
<p:autoComplete value="#{filter.value}" label="dynamic search attribute" completeMethod="#{myBean.complete}">
    <f:attribute name="filter" value="#{filter}" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

and get it by [`UIComponent#getCurrentComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29):

```java
public List<String> complete(String query) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FilterObject o = (FilterObject) UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(context).getAttributes().get("filter");
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, as that `#{filter}` appears in your case to be already in the EL scope, you can also leave the `<f:attribute>` away and get it by evaluating the EL expression programmatically with help of [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29):

```java
public List<String> complete(String query) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FilterObject o = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{filter}", FilterObject.class);
    // ...
}
```

Or, if it is also a `@Named` bean, then you can just [`@Inject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) it in the parent bean:

```java
@Inject
private FilterObject o;
```

Comment: I tried both suggested sollutions and they both worked like a charm. I chose the second approach so I wouldn't need the attribute. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I added an `@Inject` suggestion which may work out for you as well.